# How to import matrix from excel into numpy and then graph it?

Tags: python, excel, numpy, networkx

I have a matrix in excel that I am trying to import and convert to a numpy matrix and then graph it with networkx how would I go about doing this? I do have some code but not sure if I am going about doing this correctly.

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import numpy 
from numpy import genfromtxt

df=numpy.recfromcsv("Correlation_test.csv", delimiter=',', skiprows=1)

nx.Graph(df)
```

Thanks

This is what I have so far but, I keep getting an error saying "Input is not a correct numpy matrix or array".

Comment: It's better to provide the code you have with a sample data and ask specific question problems within. Your question as stated now is too broad to be ontopic for SO.

Comment: import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import numpy 
from numpy import genfromtxt
df=numpy.recfromcsv("Correlation_test.csv", delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
nx.Graph(df)

thats the code I currently have but I keep getting an error message saying "Input is not a correct numpy matrix or array."

Comment: Please edit your post to add the code instead of adding it to a comment to make it easier for us to read and answer.

Answer (score 6):

If the data is a CSV file that looks like:

#### my_graph.csv

```
My graph data
0,1,1,0,0
1,0,0,1,0
1,0,0,1,1
0,1,1,0,1
0,0,1,1,0
```

It's simple to load and plot the resulting graph:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import pylab as plt

A = np.genfromtxt("my_graph.csv",delimiter=',',skiprows=1)
G = nx.Graph(A)
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

[image]